# Why do I have a reversal If I'm not very active?

Tags: support, reputation

I have the next reputation history.

[image]

I mean, I'm all for reversals, because they help prevent people from dishonestly earning reputation, but isn't this a bit of a stretch?

Periods between votes:

- 5 days
- 1 Month
- 1+ Month

And I don't even know if it's the same person. But if it were, shouldn't they then take away all my reputation?

Comment: The following post on [meta.se] might be related: [Non-serial voting corrected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362020).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist thanks, that solves lots of questions

Answer (score 3):

The details of the vote-reversal algorithm are not public. Presumably here there was an issue with the account that gave you the votes: I *can* see which account that was, and it looks like it may have been subject to manual intervention.